# Change variable value based on row index {R}

Tags: r

## Main Problem

I am attempting to expand my dataset to copy rows but systematically change one variable (`year`) in each row based the the value of another value (`survey`). Each survey round took place over multiple years, and I would like the data to reflect this.

## Example

Data are in a data.frame, and look like this:

```
mydata:

     Region          Year          IV          DV         Survey
1    USA.Vermont     1999          1.469       6          1
2    USA.Vermont     2002          1.698       7          2
3    USA.Vermont     2005          1.556       6          3
4    USA.NewHamp     1999          0.518       2          1
5    USA.NewHamp     2002          0.698       3          2
6    USA.NewHamp     2005          0.431       1          3
```

I used `mydata.2 <- mydata[rep(1:nrow(mydata),each=3),]` and got this:

```
mydata.2:

     Region          Year          IV          DV         Survey
1    USA.Vermont     1999          1.469       6          1
1.1  USA.Vermont     1999          1.469       6          1
1.2  USA.Vermont     1999          1.469       6          1
2    USA.Vermont     2002          1.698       7          2
2.1  USA.Vermont     2002          1.698       7          2
2.2  USA.Vermont     2002          1.698       7          2
3    USA.Vermont     2005          1.556       6          3
3.1  USA.Vermont     2005          1.556       6          3
3.2  USA.Vermont     2005          1.556       6          3
4    USA.NewHamp     1999          0.518       2          1
4.1  USA.NewHamp     1999          0.518       2          1
4.2  USA.NewHamp     1999          0.518       2          1
5    USA.NewHamp     2002          0.698       3          2
5.1  USA.NewHamp     2002          0.698       3          2
5.2  USA.NewHamp     2002          0.698       3          2
6    USA.NewHamp     2005          0.431       1          3
6.1  USA.NewHamp     2005          0.431       1          3
6.2  USA.NewHamp     2005          0.431       1          3
```

That gets me close, but I would like **this** (notice the ascending values of the `year` variable):

```
mydata.2:

     Region          Year          IV          DV         Survey
1    USA.Vermont     1999          1.469       6          1
1.1  USA.Vermont     2000          1.469       6          1
1.2  USA.Vermont     2001          1.469       6          1
2    USA.Vermont     2002          1.698       7          2
2.1  USA.Vermont     2003          1.698       7          2
2.2  USA.Vermont     2004          1.698       7          2
3    USA.Vermont     2005          1.556       6          3
3.1  USA.Vermont     2006          1.556       6          3
3.2  USA.Vermont     2007          1.556       6          3
4    USA.NewHamp     1999          0.518       2          1
4.1  USA.NewHamp     2000          0.518       2          1
4.2  USA.NewHamp     2001          0.518       2          1
5    USA.NewHamp     2002          0.698       3          2
5.1  USA.NewHamp     2003          0.698       3          2
5.2  USA.NewHamp     2004          0.698       3          2
6    USA.NewHamp     2005          0.431       1          3
6.1  USA.NewHamp     2006          0.431       1          3
6.2  USA.NewHamp     2007          0.431       1          3
```

How can I accomplish this?

If more information is needed, I will happily add it!

Thank you!

Comment: `mydata.2$Year <- mydata.2$Year + sequence(rep(3,nrow(mydata))) - 1` might be what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @A.Webb, that seems to have done the trick! Thank you very much.

Comment: A variant on the version above: `mydata.2$Year <- mydata.2$Year + rep(seq(0, 2), nrow(mydata))`

Comment: Hi @alistaire, thank you very much - I will certainly try that out in future applications!