# Generating new observations by blending existing observations {R}

Tags: r

## Question

I would like to systematically change a variable (`population`) in my dataset to 'blend' intermediary rows between its current values.

## Data

I currently have data on state counties and populations at 5 year increments. The data are in a data frame.

```
data:
     year       state       county         population
1    1990       Vermont     Chittenden     4050
2    1995       Vermont     Chittenden     4180
3    2000       Vermont     Chittenden     4205
4    2005       Vermont     Chittenden     4350
5    2010       Vermont     Chittenden     4358
6    2015       Vermont     Chittenden     4401
```

Using the technique found here: [Change variable value based on row index {R}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228277/change-variable-value-based-on-row-index-r), I applied the following:

```
new.data <- data[rep(1:nrow(data),each=5),]
new.data$year <- new.data$year + sequence(rep(5,nrow(data))) -1
```

As a result, I get this:

```
new.data:
     year       state       county         population
1    1990       Vermont     Chittenden     4050
1.1  1991       Vermont     Chittenden     4050
1.2  1992       Vermont     Chittenden     4050
1.3  1993       Vermont     Chittenden     4050
1.4  1994       Vermont     Chittenden     4050
2    1995       Vermont     Chittenden     4180
2.1  1996       Vermont     Chittenden     4180
2.2  1997       Vermont     Chittenden     4180
2.3  1998       Vermont     Chittenden     4180
2.4  1999       Vermont     Chittenden     4180
3    2000       Vermont     Chittenden     4205
                        ...
5    2010       Vermont     Chittenden     4358
5.1  2010       Vermont     Chittenden     4358
5.2  2011       Vermont     Chittenden     4358
5.3  2012       Vermont     Chittenden     4358
5.4  2013       Vermont     Chittenden     4358
6    2015       Vermont     Chittenden     4401
```

However, notice that `population` does not change for five years at a time. I would like to figure out a way to 'blend' the intermediary values between the incremental values. It would look like this:

```
new.data:
     year       state       county         population
1    1990       Vermont     Chittenden     4050
1.1  1991       Vermont     Chittenden     4076
1.2  1992       Vermont     Chittenden     4102
1.3  1993       Vermont     Chittenden     4128
1.4  1994       Vermont     Chittenden     4154
2    1995       Vermont     Chittenden     4180
2.1  1996       Vermont     Chittenden     4185
2.2  1997       Vermont     Chittenden     4190
2.3  1998       Vermont     Chittenden     4195
2.4  1999       Vermont     Chittenden     4200
3    2000       Vermont     Chittenden     4205
                      ...
5    2010       Vermont     Chittenden     4358
5.1  2011       Vermont     Chittenden     4367
5.2  2012       Vermont     Chittenden     4376
5.3  2013       Vermont     Chittenden     4385
5.4  2014       Vermont     Chittenden     4394
6    2015       Vermont     Chittenden     4401
```

How can I accomplish this?

I am happy to post more information if needed. Thank you!

Comment: Look at the `seq` function.

Comment: Hi @TimothéePoisot, would you mind elaborating on that? I'm still quite new to R. I understand that `seq` allows for stipulation of both 'from' and 'to'; however, I don't know how to repeat that for each five year interval. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This kind of blending of observations is called interpolation. There are many methods for that, and one of the simplest ones is the linear interpolation that can be done as follows:

```
year <- seq(1990, 2015, by = 5)
population <- c(4050, 4180, 4205, 4350, 4358, 4401)
approx(x = year, y = population, xout = min(year):max(year))
# $x
#  [1] 1990 1991 1992 1993 ...
#
# $y
#  [1] 4050.0 4076.0 4102.0 4128.0 4154.0 4180.0 4185.0 ...
```

Also consider checking `?splines`; then the resulting curve would be "nicer" by being smoother than using the linear interpolation.

Comment: Hi @julius, thank you very much - I will try this out. I appreciate it.